# What is the default value of server.error.path in Spring Boot 2.5?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration, properties-file

In Spring Boot, what is the default value of server.error.path property in application.properties file?

If I want it to be "/error", am I required to define it or it is "/error" automatically and it must be defined only if I want it to be something different than that?

Context:

getErrorPath() of ErrorController is deprecated and I don't see the need to specifically set server.error.path in application.properties if my value is "/error".

Answer (score 0):

/error is the default and you should not need to do anything extra in your config. Spring Boot will usually select sensible defaults. If you need to customize the display of your error page add the file error.html to your src/main/resources/templates folder.  I include Thymeleaf in my projects and here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Error</title>
  <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Error Occurred - Details Below</h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td th:text="${timestamp}"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Path</td>
      <td th:text="${path}"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Error</td>
      <td th:text="${error}"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td th:text="${status}"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Message</td>
      <td th:text="${message}"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Exception</td>
      <td th:text="${exception}"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trace</td>
      <td>
        <pre th:text="${trace}"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also tweak other error settings for Spring Boot.  Here are a few (YML example):

```
server:
  error:
   include-exception: true
   include-stacktrace: always
   include-message: always
```

I use this setup for development only (dev profile).  I typically do not show exceptions or stacktrace for production (prod profile).